# How to deserialize timestamp with offset into Instant

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a json with timestamp having offsets from UTC (e.g., `2023-05-04T19:40:07.000+0200`). How to deserialize it into `java.time.Instant`)?

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.time.Instant;

public class MyInstantTest {

    @Test
    void test1() throws JsonProcessingException {

        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
                .disable(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
                .disable(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS);

        final MyClass deserializedObject = objectMapper.readValue("{\"time\":\"2023-05-04T19:40:07.000+0200\"}", MyClass.class);

//        com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.Instant` from String 
//        "2023-05-04T19:40:07.000+0200": Failed to deserialize java.time.Instant: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text 
//        '2023-05-04T19:40:07.000+0200' could not be parsed at index 23
//        at [Source: (String)"{"time":"2023-05-04T19:40:07.000+0200"}"; line: 1, column: 9] (through reference chain: com.example.e
//        .f.g.h.i.j.MyInstantTest$MyClass["time"])

        System.out.println("deserializedObject.getTime() = " + deserializedObject.getTime());
    }

    static class MyClass {

        MyClass() {

        }

        MyClass(Instant time) {

            this.time = time;
        }

        public Instant getTime() {

            return time;
        }

        public void setTime(final Instant time) {

            this.time = time;
        }

        private Instant time;
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to do `OffsetDateTime.parse(val).toInstant()` but you'll need to fix up the offset to `+02:00`

Comment: The work is easier if you use the fully expanded standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. Always include the optional COLON character delimiting the hours and minutes of the offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your own formatter:

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.Instant;
// :
// :
DateTimeFormatter customFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSx");
Instant result = Instant.from(customFormatter.parse("2023-05-04T19:40:07.000+0200"));
```

(At the end you have to create a new `Instant` from the formatters parsing result, if you need exactly that class.)